# Order by rand() in yii2

Tags: mysql, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

I want to write following query in `yii2`, but I can't get the expected output:

```
SELECT * FROM user where category_id=5 ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 4
```

For that I have done following:

```
$data= User::find()->where(['category_id'=> 5])->orderBy(['rand()'])->limit(4);
```

But it generates the command like following

```
SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `category_id`=5 ORDER BY `0` LIMIT 4
```

Which is not a valid mysql statement,so what should I do to get the query right?

My aim is to get any random 4 records from `user` table.

Comment: Unless you don't care about performance, never order by `rand()`. It's [terribly inefficient](https://www.warpconduit.net/2011/03/23/selecting-a-random-record-using-mysql-benchmark-results/).

Comment: @Beowulfenator got it thank you. I used the method in the conclusion on that article.

Comment: Read the article. There are different solutions there and a graph that shows how they perform on different data sets. It is not relevant how many records you need to find, it's more important how many total entries you have in the table.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Wrap it into [yii\db\Expression](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-expression.html) to prevent escaping and remove array part:

```
use yii\db\Expression;

...

$query = User::find()
    ->where(['category_id' => 5])
    ->orderBy(new Expression('rand()'))
    ->limit(4);
```

Comment: thats nice. Its working perfectly. And can you help me with the `Limit` not working in `ActiveDataProvider` part? what am i doing wrong there?

Comment: That's different question, the current problem is solved.

Comment: for limit @arogachev  provide an answer to another question this is the link [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33748211/limit-is-not-working-in-activedataprovider)

Comment: please change Expresssion('rand()') to Expression('rand()')

Comment: @sj59 Done, thanks for remark. By the way, you can suggest edit for any post too.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not really an expert on yii2 query builder, however, specify the ordering should help

```
$data= User::find()->where(['category_id'=> 5])->orderBy(['rand()' => SORT_DESC])->limit(4);
```

Comment: spot on. That was the problem but still the `limit` doesnt work  in `ActiveDataProvider`. Any thoughts?

Comment: just set pagination to false and then manual setting of limit will work