# LIMIT is not working in ActiveDataProvider

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

I am using following code and the `limit` doesnt work. But if I see the command than it shows `limit` in that, but when I pass the query to `ActiveDataProvider` it fetch all the records:

```
$data= User::find()->where(['category_id'=> 5])->orderBy(['rand()' => SORT_DESC])->limit(4);

    $command = $data->createCommand();

    $data2 = $command->queryAll();// This works fine and fetch only 4 data 

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $data,

    ]); // But this displays all data without limit
```

What is wrong I am doing here?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Here is what happens when preparing models in `yii\data\ActiveDataProvider`:

```
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
protected function prepareModels()
{
    if (!$this->query instanceof QueryInterface) {
        throw new InvalidConfigException('The "query" property must be an instance of a class that implements the QueryInterface e.g. yii\db\Query or its subclasses.');
    }
    $query = clone $this->query;
    if (($pagination = $this->getPagination()) !== false) {
        $pagination->totalCount = $this->getTotalCount();
        $query->limit($pagination->getLimit())->offset($pagination->getOffset());
    }
    if (($sort = $this->getSort()) !== false) {
        $query->addOrderBy($sort->getOrders());
    }

    return $query->all($this->db);
}
```

We're interested in this part:

```
if (($pagination = $this->getPagination()) !== false) {
    $pagination->totalCount = $this->getTotalCount();
    $query->limit($pagination->getLimit())->offset($pagination->getOffset());
}
```

So as you can see if pagination is not `false`, limit is managed automatically.

You can just set pagination to `false` and then manual setting of limit will work:

```
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => $query,
    'pagination' => false,
]);
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use Limit in the **ActiveDataProvider** and keep **Pagination** like so:-

```
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
         'pagination' => [
             'pageSize' => 50, 
         ],
    ]);
$dataProvider->setTotalCount(1000);
```

This will make `$this->getTotalCount() = 1000` and Keep the pagination.
Go [here](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/output-data-providers) and [here](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-data-basedataprovider#$pagination-detail) for more reference.