# how to limit query for ActiveDataProvider?

Tags: mysql, yii2, cactivedataprovider

I am trying to make a query to get the first **10 records** for example, and pass it to the `ActiveDataProvider`.

The query is working fine and returning the required number of records only, while the `ActiveDataProvider` is printing all the records, here is my code:

```
    $query = new \yii\db\Query;
    $query->select('*')
            ->from('customers')
            ->limit(10);
    $query->createCommand();

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);
```

Comment: i think this question was already asked you should search first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set `Pagination` to `false` :

```
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
'pagination' => false
]);
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33748211/limit-is-not-working-in-activedataprovider)

Comment: I don't want to use pagination, the data provided must not exceed the specified limit.

Comment: @Mohammad. See Updated answer.

Comment: @Mohammad mark as accepted.

Comment: @InsaneSkull i think you should use false and not 'false' (in this case the result is the same, but the concept is different )

Comment: @scaisEdge Thanks, typo error.

Comment: @scaisEdge good catch, I tried false from the beginning because 'false' didn't work.

Comment: @InsaneSkull : hi, how can setting pagination false get the intended result ? what is the relation between pagination and query limit?

Comment: @Bloodhound.  see **Reference** link of my answer.

Comment: @InsaneSkull i have commented on that answer. I forgot sorry